# Изменение части строк в pandas

Tags: pandas

У меня есть датафрейм со строчками такого вида:

> str_1 | str_2 | str_3 | number_1 | number_2 |... | number_n

Я хочу каждое число в такое строчке поделить на сумму всех остальных чисел в этой строчке, оставив все остальные значения. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С созданием временной колонки можно так

```
df['sum'] = df.loc[:,"number_1":"number_3"].sum(axis=1)
df.loc[:,"number_1":"number_3"] = df.loc[:,"number_1":"number_3"].div(df["sum"], axis=0)
```